# i want to validate my form if the mobile no is already present in back end

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angularjs-directive

i'm getting the response from back end that the mobile no is already present or is a new mobile no.but unable to to show the validation in my form that the mobile no is already registered.can anyone help me with that.

```
<div>
    <md-content ng-app="shoppingPad" ng-controller="loginController">
        <p class="Welcome-to-ShoppingP">Welcome to ShoppingPad</p>
        <div>
            <form name="myForm" ng-app="shoppingPad" class="myForm" ng-submit="submit()">
                <div class="row formData">
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <md-input-container>
                            <md-icon md-svg-icon="assets/images/device.svg"></md-icon>
                            <input type="number" placeholder="Enter user mobile no" name="mobile" id="mobile" ng-model="mobile" required phone-number-validator minlength="10">
                                <div ng-messages="myForm.mobile.$error">
                                <div ng-message="required">Registered mobile no.</div>
                                    <div ng-message="phoneNumber">The mobile No entered has already been registered</div>
                                <div ng-message="test">too short</div>
                            </div>
                        </md-input-container>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <md-input-container>
                            <md-icon md-svg-icon="assets/images/lock.svg"></md-icon>
                            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter 3-D secure pin" name="password" id="password" ng-model="password" required minlength="6">
                            <div ng-messages="myForm.password.$error">
                                <div ng-message="required">Enter Pin no.</div>
                                <div ng-message="minlength">too short</div>
                            </div>
                        </md-input-container>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end of login form-->

                <!-- login toolbar-->
                <div>
                <md-toolbar class="loginToolBar">
                    <md-button class="md-primary" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" style="margin-top: 15px;outline: none;" ng-click="login()">LOGIN</md-button>
                </md-toolbar>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </md-content>

</div>


angular.module('shoppingPad').directive('phoneNumberValidator',phoneNumberValidator)


function phoneNumberValidator($q,restService){
    var deferred=$q.defer();
    return{
        restrict:'EA',
        require:'ngModel',

        link:function($scope,element,attrs,ngModel){
            ngModel.$asyncValidators.phoneNumber=function(modelValue , viewValue) {

                var mobile= (modelValue || viewValue).toString();
                console.log(mobile);
                ngModel.$asyncValidators.userMobile=function(mobile){
                    return restService.getRequest('save/all',null).then(function(response){
                            console.log("inside get");

                            return deferred.promise;
                        },
                        function(error){
                            deferred.reject(error);
                            return deferred.promise;
                        }
                    )
                };

            }


        }
    }
}
```